# Execute Javascript Function from From

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Sorry for this simple question but I can't find the answer anywhere...I'm also a Javascript newbie with 0 experience so I'm really stuck.

Anyways, I have a function that is used with a simple button click:

```
<input type="button" value="Add Item" onclick="addToCartt('MODELNUMBER');">
```

I need to change that from the current setup where you can click and hit a button and run the function with the ModelNumber argument into a form where you enter the ModelNumber manually and hit return via an html form and run the function addToCartt with the ModelNumber as the argument.

Thanks for any help

```
function addToCartt(product_id, quantity) {
      quantity = typeof(quantity) != 'undefined' ? quantity : 1;

      $.ajax({
        url: 'index.php?route=checkout/cart/addorder',
        type: 'post',
        data: 'product_id=' + product_id + '&quantity=' + quantity,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(json) {
          $('.success, .warning, .attention, .information, .error').remove();



        $('#maincontent').addClass('active');
        $('#maincontent').load('index.php?route=module/cart');
        // $('#cart').live('mouseleave', function() {
        // $(this).removeClass('active');
        // });


          if (json['redirect']) {
            location = json['redirect'];
          }

          if (json['success']) {
            $('#notification').html('<div class="success" style="display: none;">' + json['success'] + '<img src="close.png" alt="" class="close" /></div>');

            $('.success').fadeIn('slow');

            $('#cart-total').html(json['total']);
            $('#new_total').html(json['new_total']);

            // $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 'slow'); 
          } 
        }
      });
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HTML:

```
<form name='frm'>
    <input type='text' id='model' />
</form>
```

javascript:

```
$(function() {
    $('#model').keypress(function(e){
        if (e.which === 13) {
            $(frm).submit()
        }
    });
    $('form').submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        addToCart($('#model').val());
    });
});
```

if model is the only input in your form, you don't need the keypress event.

Comment: Tried this but it didn't work. I also added the actual function to the question, you think you could have another look? I really appreciate the help Nicolás.

Comment: add a return false to the end of the function. this will short-circuit the http submit. you can also (and should) bind the function to the event using jQuery. I'll update my answer with this code right away

Comment: Thanks but I'm getting an error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected Token from adding this function.

Comment: should work now, I had an extra parens in my $('#model').keypress code

Comment: Sorry, it's still refreshing the page. Not sure why.

Comment: now it should. I forgot to wrap the frm object in a $() so the event is triggered correctly and the submit binding is called

Comment: Awesome it works but now it submits it twice. Any ideas? Thanks so much by the way.

Comment: if model is the only input in the form, then you don't need the $('#model') code. if you include it, the form will be submitted twice (via the browser and programmatically via the keypress event.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably the HTML you want. Without being able to see your JavaScript I can't really help more than this:

```
<form onsubmit="return addToCart();">
   <input type="text" value"MODELNUMBER" />
   <input type="submit" value="Add Item"/>
</form>
```

You'll need to return false from your `addToCart` to prevent the form from submitting a new page load. If you use jQuery you can also call `preventDefault` on the event argument.

Comment: Just added the function to question

Comment: Checkout @nicolas's answer. He's got it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the value from the html input.
With jQuery would be like this:

```
<input type="button" value="Add Item" onclick="addToCart($('#modelNumber').val());">
```